# gnutls vs openssl with openldap, debian and centos

Tags: centos, debian, openldap, openssl, gnutls

I have a Debian 6.0.5 server running openldap. It appears to be compiled against gnutls. I used gnutls' certtool to generate a self-signed certificate and I have used it on a few debian client machines to authenticate against the openldap server.

However, when I try to do the same on a CentOS 6 client, I get the following error for ldapsearch:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )    
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
additional info: TLS error -8101:Certificate type not approved for application.    
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

If I run gnutls-cli-debug on the CentOS client, I get the following:

```
gnutls-cli-debug -p 636 ldap.blahblah.com
    Resolving 'ldap.blahblah.com'...
    Connecting to '10.6.0.11:636'...
    Error in %INITIAL_SAFE_RENEGOTIATION
    Checking for Safe renegotiation support...
```

And that's it - it dies.

Has anyone been able to do ldaps in this kind of a setup, gnutls linked server, gnutls generated certificate, openssl linked client?

Thanks!

Comment: Try 389DS from EPEL repo. Actually, as LDAP I like it more, but couldn't make SSL work despite it's nice interface :D

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could attack this in one of two ways: getting the `ldapsearch` client to work using your existing certificates, or generating new certificates that it likes. Personally, I'd imagine modifying your server certificate to be easier than changing the `ldapsearch` code, so that's what I looked at.

The error above suggests that something is lacking in your server-side certificate (ie the client doesn't want to talk to your server because it's not identifying properly).

For starters, I examined the certificate used by a random LDAP server, in this case `directory.washington.edu`. If you snag its certificate, eg:

```
openssl s_client -connect directory.washington.edu:636 > dirwash.crt
```

and then do:

```
openssl x509 -in dirwash.crt -text
```

you'll see:

```
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
```

Other LDAP servers (eg `ldap.virginia.edu`) don't have those extensions at all. Others, like `ldap.itd.umich.edu` have a variation of the above:

```
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

In short, I suggest that you check your server certificate – post it here if you like – to see whether it contains `X509v3 (Extended) Key Usage` extensions and, if so, whether those look like ones in use on other LDAP servers.

I saw a [mail thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/mozilla-crypto@mozilla.org/msg01541.html) that suggested that either: (1) the extensions should be absent; or (2) if the extensions are present, they need to contain at least `TLS Web Server Authentication`. I don't know if that's true in this case, but something to consider anyhow.